# correct tightening torque for a noname single lever mixer tap

Tags: plumbing

Some days ago, i have checked the ceramic cartridge of my sink mixer tap.

I opened and cleaned it and I now have a leak from under the lever. I think I'm not tightening enough the nut, so the water is leaking (only when the lever is actionned).

I don't want to over tighten it. What is the correct tightening torque for that kind of single lever mixer tap? (For information, the tightening nut is 32 mm large.)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure torque values are the right way to go about this since many things can affect a torque reading here. Most plumbers don't use torque wrenches.

Instead, make sure all the seats and seals are clean and in good condition. It shouldn't take much torque to get a seal. It's not usually screw pressure that creates the seal, but o-rings that fit between the walls of parts, creating their own pressure, as well as internal springs.